# Script Access wrong calendar account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have a script that integrate with my spreadsheet, when edit i want the script to check the owned script/static calendar account.

(ex): I have two account accessing my spreadsheet,

1.user@gmail.com

2.admin@gmail.com

When `user@gmail.com` edit my spreadsheet the script will check/edit calendar inside `admin@gmail.com`.

The script & spreadsheet is owned by `admin@gmail.com`.

At the development i used user@gmail.com to create and edit the script, but when i want to used `admin@gmail.com` the calendar return `user@gmail.com` calendar even the user that perform the trigger is `admin@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An installable trigger always runs on behalf of the person who created the trigger.

If you want to permanently change the trigger owner from `user@gmail.com` to `admin@gmail.com`, just delete the trigger and create a new one from the account of `admin@gmail.com`.